# radio buttons + input field for one of them

Tags: javascript

I tried the following but it returns two pieces of data to the server. This is a problem for my gateway, and I get an error.

I used this for one of my attempts:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if( $('#other).is('):selected') ) 
 {
   // user wants to enter own value
 $('[name="installments"]").not('[type="text"]').attr('name', '') // remove all      
  values apart from the entered text.
 }
 </script>

<body>
<FORM ACTION="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi" METHOD="POST">
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="installments" id="r1" checked="checked" value="99">
&nbsp;Open-Ended - I can stop them via email at any time.<br>
<label for="installments">number of payments</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="installments" id="other" value="Enter Custom.."><br>
<input type="text" name="installments" value="" maxlength="4" size="4">
 <br><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This returns either -

```
installments 99 
installments (empty)
```

or

```
installments Enter Custom.. 
installments 5
```

I can only have one return for the var 'installments' either 99 or the number they imputed.
I have tried various ways of doing this using JS and allowing the user to make a choice with the same results - two instances of the var 'installments' being sent.

Is there a javascript way to test the input field and if a number is entered then disable using id(s) the extra radio button so it can't send any data?  Or is there a better way to do this?

---

#### Solved

I found the answer & Here it is

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $('#user_input').change(function() {
  $('#use_user_input').val($(this).val());
  });
 });
</script>
```

And Html Here:

```
 Total number of payments...</span><br>
 <input type="radio" name="installments" checked value="99"> &nbsp;
        Open-Ended -
 <input id="use_user_input" type="radio" name="installments" value=""> &nbsp;
        limited number of payments - &nbsp;
<input id="user_input" type="text" value="" maxlength="4" size="4"></span>
```

Comment: The status of the radio buttons is one set of data, which will tell you whether the text field, a separate piece of data, is relevant. The answer below, naming your text field differently, should make the difference.

Comment: But I can't as I'm sending this data to a gateway and they set what vars and data they will accept.  I can only send the var installments one time, and it's required.  I wouldn't have any problem if I were processing the form data....

Comment: in this case you need to send them as separate forms. I will look back later today to see if this is still unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to give the input text field a different name from the radio inputs, then handle the text field's POST as a separate variable from the radio buttons in the HTTP request.  Also, give the second radio input a value, such as "other" so you know to handle the associated text input.

Comment: So let me see if I follow you.                                      <input type="radio" name="installments" checked value="99"> 
    <br>
 <input type="radio" name="other" value="other"> 
 limited number  - 
  <input type="text" name="installments" value="" maxlength="4" size="4">                                                             Is this right?

Comment: But what I've got now won't change the 'installments' value from 99 to a number they input.... so I guess I don't follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the ability to receive one field from the form you will need to alter the form as the user fills it in. Currently the form works if the user selects one of the values delimited by the radio buttons. The problem, I gather, is that the status of the radio buttons overrides the value of the text field even if the user selects the "other" option of filling in the text box.

The solution is to use a script that is triggered when the user changes the content of the text box. This script will read the value of the text box and assign that value to the 'other' radio button.

We can do this using the `onchange` event:

```
<input id="otherRadio" type="radio" name="installments" value="" /><br />
<input id="otherText" type="text" value="" maxlength="4" size="4" onchange="applyOtherOption()" />
```

If you try this now, it will cause a javascript error on your page when you change the value of the the text field. This is because the browser fails to find a javascript function with the name `applyOtherOption`. Let's change that now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function applyOtherOption() {
        var textField = document.getElementById("otherText");
        var radioField = document.getElementById("otherRadio");

        radioField.value = textField.value;
    }
</script>
```

The result is that the "other" radio button's value is always changed to whatever the user enters into the text field and if this radio is selected, this is what is sent with the form.

**Important**
I've been a bit lazy here and typed out the easiest way to access the content of the form elements. This will work on most (probably all major) browsers but it is not the way it should be done. The proper method is to access the form first, then from the form element access the fields. To do it right you should read this article [on setting the value of form elements](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-value.phtml).

I hope this is useful.